# Getting a value in a row from a column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.5

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|Student ID |   Name   | Username | Password | Moderator |
----------------------------------------------------------    
|   0001    | Foo Bar  |   test   |   abc123  |     N    |
|   0002    |  Baz Qux |   bob    |   bcd986  |     Y    |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

How would I go about getting a value in a row from a column value ?

For example, if I had the username 'test' how can I get the value of 'Name' in the corresponding row (Foo Bar)?

Comment: Do you have these `|, - ` delimiters in file or you just added them for readability?

Comment: you read the csv line by line, split it, check for `test` in 3rd place, if yes `return second element`

Comment: @Anthony Added that for readability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reading a csv file with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
# Here you can use pd.read_csv() instead
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

### Accessing value in a row from a column value

```
df[df.Username == 'test']['Name']
```

[out]:

```
0    Foo Bar
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

If you need the result as a string:

```
df[df.Username == 'test'].Name.values[0]
```

[out]:

```
'Foo Bar'
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. When I try `print(df[df.Username == 'admin'].Name.values[0])` I get the error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Name'` however, I done `print(df)` and the Name is present, `df[df.Username == 'admin'].Password.values[0]` and `df[df.Username == 'admin'].Moderator.values[0]` works though. Any idea why Name isn't working? Also how would I get columns with spaces e.g:``df[df.Username == 'admin'].Ful Name.values[0]` returns a syntax error.

Comment: Try print(df[df.Username == 'admin']['Name'].values[0])

Answer (score 1):

There are several option to achieve your task. *First*, as @michaelg proposed, using `pandas` - it's fast and library handles it very well. Here is a link for [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/). *Second* option would be a build in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#). There you can find a short example of `scv reader` with delimiters. And the third option would be just to treat your `.scv` file as an ordinary file. For instance,

```
with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    # we skip first line because it is your header,
    # e.g. id, name, pswd, etc.
    for line in data[1:]:
        for field in line.split("|"): # place your delimiter
            # strip data of leading and trailing whitespaces 
            print(field.strip())
```

You can use this approach to search for you corresponding value. The snippet above would produce this output:

```
0001
Foo Bar
test
abc123
N
```

If you want to access values by their indexes, use this:

```
with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    values = [x.split("|") for x in data[1:]]
```

The above snippet would give you a `list` of this format `[[..], [..],..]` where `values[0]` is your line 1 of your file and `values[0][1]` = `"Foo Bar"` name.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative `csv` answer.

Answer (score 0):

The format is not really a csv. You could rewrite it into something usefull and parse that with DictReader:

```
import csv

def rewriteCsv(filename): 
    """Rewrite silly file into something usefull"""
    header = None
    rwfn = "mod_"+filename
    with open (filename,"r") as r, open(rwfn,"w") as w:
        for row in r:
            if row.startswith("---"):
                continue # skip it
            if not header:
                header = ','.join(x.strip() for x in row.split("|") if x.strip())
                w.write(header+'\n')
                continue

            w.write(','.join( x.strip() for x in row.strip()[1:-1].split("|") ) +"\n")
    return rwfn

def createFile(filename):
    """Create the silly file..."""
    with open(filename,"w") as f:
        f.write("""----------------------------------------------------------
|Student ID |   Name   | Username | Password | Moderator |
----------------------------------------------------------    
|   0001    | Foo Bar  |   test   |   abc123  |     N    |
|   0002    |  Baz Qux |   bob    |   bcd986  |     Y    |
----------------------------------------------------------
""")

createFile("file.txt") # create the silly one
fn = rewriteCsv("file.txt") # rewrite into something useful

with open(fn,"r") as r: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(r)
    for row in reader: # access earch ordered dict by columnname
        print(row["Student ID"], row["Name"], row["Username"])
```